# Securing WPF Web Service for Android App usage only

Tags: android, wpf, web-services

So I am planning on building a web service that an Android app will connect to. I am trying to come up with a way to secure this web service so it will only be used via the App.

I was thinking just passing a secret key along with each call I make. But this can easily be compromised with an http sniffer. Then the web service can be used with anyone at that point.

Are there any other ways to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can FORCE Android only. Whatever method you use can be worked around if they know what it is.

Depending on how the app is written, it should be simple enough to check the User-Agent of the request. Apps that use the HttpUrlConnection (as recommended by the Android docs) should have a user-agent string that says Android in it.